# Is there a Delphi equivalent to java's OnReceive Function?

Tags: java, delphi, bluetooth, java-native-interface, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to record audio from a Bluetooth device using Delphi's Android JNI framework.

I am using the `MediaRecorder` class, as I need the maximum amplitude of the audio source.

I have been following the example code that was given here:

[How to record audio via bluetooth mic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29626247/)

I have run into a problem of not knowing how to implement the `OnReceive` function that he has. It seems to be an event, but I don't know if there is a Delphi equivalent that I can use to go about solving this.

I am using RAD Studio 10.2 Toyko.

Answer (score 1):

[`onReceive()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#onReceive(android.content.Context,%20android.content.Intent)) is a virtual method of Android's [`BroadcastReceiver`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) class.

The code you refer to is creating an object instance of the `BroadcastReceiver` class, overriding its `onReceive()` method, and registering that object with Android via the [`Context.registerReceiver()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#registerReceiver(android.content.BroadcastReceiver,%20android.content.IntentFilter)) method.

There are plenty of online tutorials and examples of using Android Broadcast Receivers in Delphi, if you look around.